# How do I get around "DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR: prepared statement already exists " error

Tags: perl, bash, dbd

A little background:
I have a perl script which is performing a number of operations inside of a loop.

Inside of the loop, I create a prepared statement like so:

```
  // inside loop
  my $statement = "select xxxx from zzzzzz where $foobar;";
  my $query = $connect->prepare($statement);
  $query->execute();
```

$foobar is updated to a new value everytime the loop completes, which is why i want to change the query every run, however I am getting an error when I try to do so.

When the script is run I get this error:

```
  DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  prepared statement "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" already exists at
```

Because I am passing a variable which is updated every time the loop runs, and assuming I need to use this prepared statement, how do I get around this error?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**

For future people having this problem, check this out here :

I was trying to get

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select interval ?');
```

http://gborg.postgresql.org/pipermail/dbdpg-general/2006-January/001972.html

http://gborg.postgresql.org/pipermail/dbdpg-general/2006-February/002007.html

list some workarounds: either turning off the server-side prepares
through the pg_server_prepare flag or using eg. '?::interval' instead of
'interval ?'

Comment: What versions of *everything* (perl, Postgres libs, Postgres server, DBI, DBD::Pg) are you using?  This may be a [bug in a recent DBD::Pg](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.bug-tracking.request-tracker.user/65741).

Comment: Just to be clear, the 'interval ?' issue is a *syntax error* generated by the Pg backend when asked to prepare a statement, behavior which was introduced around 2006 when the DBD driver introduced true server-side preparation.  The 'prepared statement already exists' issue which opened this question has a different root cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your prepared statement outside of the loop.  If you have a variable that needs to be passed to the prepared statement, you'll use the `?` marker to pass in the variable to the prepared statement.  Here's an example:

```
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?');
foreach ... {

    my $var = <something>;
    $stmt->execute($var);
}
```

Here, the prepared statement is created once, and the `?` is used to pass in variables.  When you call execute, you pass in the variable as parameters.

Comment: Can the same thing be done with more than one variable? Such as 

my $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND name ='?'");

$stmt->execute($var1,$var2);

??

Comment: @BeauBouchard Yep, and that's exactly how you do it.  `$var1` would be matched to `id` and `$var2` would be matched to `name` in your example.

Comment: well you got me over that hump, thanks, marking your answer as correct, although now I get 

DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: SELECT $1 + interval '5 seconds'
                         ^ at ./xxxscriptxxxx.pl line 516.

I am passing in a string, and i am not sure how to use "'" marks. but thank for all your help

Comment: or I get DBD::Pg::st execute failed: called with 1 bind variables when 0 are needed at ./tedect_dev.pl line 516.
 when I do  $connect->prepare("SELECT timestamp '?' + interval '5 seconds'");

Comment: Found may answer :D thank for all your help http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/dbi/ch05_03.htm 
  $sth->bind_param( 1, "WHERE name = 'Avebury'" );

Comment: I'm suprised binding a parameter as "where name = 'Avebury'" works at all as it changes the SQL. Normally you can only bind a column value. i.e. it would be better as "select x where y = ?" and then you bind a value for y.

Comment: You don't use quotes when you use bound parameters. `$dbh->prepare(" SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND name = ? ");`